# Display all posts whose IDs are passed through url

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I want to get all the posts in wordpress whose ids are passed in parameter like 
http://localhost/wordpres/**?pid=181,109,5,1**

My front-page.php have following code

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php
                if ('posts' == get_option('show_on_front')) {
                    get_template_part('content', 'posts');
                } else {
                    get_template_part('content', 'page');
                }
                // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template
                if (comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number()) :
                    comments_template();
                endif;
                ?>
            <?php endwhile;} // end of the loop.   ?>
```

And I have tried  **query_posts('p=181');** with **http://localhost/wordpres/?pid=109** for single post; it works fine. 
But I can't sort out how to give query_posts multiple post ids which are passed through url. Need help.

Comment: I think you're looking for [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37603/how-do-i-get-posts-by-multiple-post-ids)

Comment: @DouwedeHaan  I tried 
$args = array(
    'post__in' => array(43,23,65)
);
but i can't understand how to get the post ids from url as array

Comment: Are you able to alter the url? Because if you want an array straight away, you should use something like `?pid[]=181&pid[]=109&pid[]=5&pid[]=1`. Otherwise, a simple explode would suffice: `explode(',', $_GET['pid'])`, which returns an array with the ID's

Comment: thanks for the help @DouwedeHaan

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code existing above code to solve your problem.

```
<?php 
$all_posts = sanitize_text_field($_GET['pid']);
if(!empty($all_posts)){
    $all_posts = explode(',', $all_posts);
}else{
    $all_posts = array();
}
$args = array( 
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post__in' => $all_posts
        );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        get_template_part('content', 'posts');
        if (comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number()) :
            comments_template();
        endif;
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
    echo "no posts found";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it by using following code

```
$thePostIdArray = explode(',', $_GET['pid']);
             $args = array(
                   'post__in'      => $thePostIdArray
                );

                query_posts($args);?>
             <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php
                if ('posts' == get_option('show_on_front')) {
                    get_template_part('content', 'posts');
                } else {
                    get_template_part('content', 'page');
                }
```